# How to use aggregate and sum while writing to MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I'm complete beginner with mongodb, javascript and coding overall, this part of my project is giving me hard times.
I have read manuals in mongodb websites, tried look from here practical example for my case, but with bad results.

Wanted action is to read values to variables from webpage and write sum from some of those variables to separate record in that document in MongoDB.

First of all, shall I do that in Schema, model, or in route?

I have been trying to do that in route, like example below shows.

```
router.post('/xxxxxxx', function(req, res){

console.log('function called!!');
 var xxxx = req.body.xxxx;
 var xxxx1 = req.body.xxxx1;
 var xxxx2;
 var score1;
 var score2;
 var score3;
 var score4;
 var score5 = 

 **scoresh.aggregate([

      {$group:{
               score5: {$sum :{
                               score1,
                               score2,
                               score3,
                               score4,**

           }
         }
       }
    }
])

// Validation
req.checkBody('xxxx', 'xxxx').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('xxxx', 'xxxxxxxx').notEmpty();

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
    res.render('xxxxxxxxx',{
        errors:errors
    });
} else {
    console.log('succes');
    var newXxxxxx = new xxxxxxxx({
        score1 : req.body.score1,
        score2 : req.body.score2,
        score3 : req.body.score3,
        score4 : req.body.score4,
        score5 : req.body.score5,
        .
        .

 Score.createScore(newScore, function(err, Score){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('success');
        });

        req.flash('success_msg', 'Succes.');

        res.redirect('/xxxxx/xxxxx');

}
});
module.exports = router;
```

If i write numeric value, example 33 to  -score5 : 33- , it will write it to database, but i can't get that $summ of other scores to that -score5-.

Hopefully someone more experienced can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

As I have been wrestling with this and I made workaround. And I think this aint anything .pretty() but i just made at the end variable and joined that parseInt(req.body.score1) + ...   Classy huh? ;) well.. learning curve is at start.  Hopefully someone as new as I am can get something out of this.